# Kivy drabable rows in a list

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

The user should be able to drag the rows to reorder them. In the current implementation its simply buttons, but a drag is much more user friendly

This code is only working after it got moved a little, right in the beginning some elements are stuck in the place and cant be moved. I am not sure if its the on_touch_down or the init which makes the behaviour.

I am using kivy 2.3.0
and py 3.11

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.behaviors import DragBehavior
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle

class DraggableLabel(DragBehavior, Label):
    def __init__(self, label_text, description_text, **kwargs):
        super(DraggableLabel, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.text = f"{label_text}: {description_text}"
        self.size_hint_y = None
        self.height = 40
        self.drag_touch = None
        self.original_index = 0

        with self.canvas.before:
            Color(0.4, 0.7, 0.9, 1)  # Set the background color (R, G, B, A)
            self.rect = Rectangle(pos=self.pos, size=self.size)

        self.bind(pos=self.update_rect, size=self.update_rect)
        

    def update_rect(self, *args):
        self.rect.pos = self.pos
        self.rect.size = self.size

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos) and not self.drag_touch:
            self.drag_touch = touch
            self.original_index = self.parent.children.index(self)
            return super(DraggableLabel, self).on_touch_down(touch)
        return super(DraggableLabel, self).on_touch_down(touch)

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        if touch == self.drag_touch:
            self.y = touch.y - self.height / 2

            # Update the position in the list while still dragging
            target_index = round(self.y / self.height)
            target_index = max(0, min(target_index, len(self.parent.elements) - 1))

            if self.original_index < target_index:
                target_index -= 1

            if target_index != self.original_index:
                self.parent.reorder_elements(self.original_index, self)
                self.original_index = target_index

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        if touch == self.drag_touch:
            self.parent.reorder_elements(self.original_index, self)
            self.drag_touch = None
            return True
        return super(DraggableLabel, self).on_touch_up(touch)

class ReorderableList(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, elements, **kwargs):
        super(ReorderableList, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation = 'vertical'
        self.spacing = 5
        self.elements = []

        for element in elements:
            label = DraggableLabel(label_text=element['label'],
                                    description_text=element['description'])
            self.add_widget(label)
            self.elements.append(label)

    def reorder_elements(self, original_index, dragged_label):
            dragged_index = self.elements.index(dragged_label)

            target_index = round(dragged_label.y / dragged_label.height)
            target_index = max(0, min(target_index, len(self.elements) - 1))

            if original_index < target_index:
                target_index -= 1

            dragged_widget = self.elements.pop(original_index)
            self.remove_widget(dragged_widget)

            self.elements.insert(target_index, dragged_widget)
            self.add_widget(dragged_widget, index=target_index)

class DragAndDropApp(App):
    def build(self):
        elements = [
            {'label': 'Item 1', 'description': 'Description 1'},
            {'label': 'Item 2', 'description': 'Description 2'},
            {'label': 'Item 3', 'description': 'Description 3'},
            {'label': 'Item 4', 'description': 'Description 4'},
            {'label': 'Item 5', 'description': 'Description 5'},
            {'label': 'Item 6', 'description': 'Description 6'},
            {'label': 'Item 7', 'description': 'Description 7'},
            {'label': 'Item 8', 'description': 'Description 8'},
            {'label': 'Item 9', 'description': 'Description 9'},
            {'label': 'Item 10', 'description': 'Description 10'},
        ]

        return ReorderableList(elements)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    DragAndDropApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only problem in your code is two lines in `reorder_elements()`. Try changing:

```
dragged_widget = self.elements.pop(original_index)
```

to:

```
dragged_widget = dragged_label
self.elements.remove(dragged_widget)
```

and change:

```
self.elements.insert(target_index, dragged_widget)
```

to:

```
self.elements.insert(-target_index, dragged_widget)
```

Keep in mind that the order of widgets in the `children` of `ReorderableList` are in the opposite order that they appear in the GUI and opposite the order in your `elements` list.