# Kivy recycleview + dragable components

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

I tried implementing an dragable row, into a recycleview because a boxlayout is limited in the amount of "rows". [Stackoverflow example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77873371/kivy-drabable-rows-in-a-list/77875122#77875122). This implementation was working, but when implementing it with a recycle view i had many issues.
I feel like i am almost at the finish line, just the "calculation" where an object is, and when to change position is buggy, one thing is that on screen there might only be 10 elements but in the list are 20, for example.

I disabled the drag scrolling in the recycleview

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, ListProperty, NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.uix.behaviors import DragBehavior

kv = """
<DraggableRow>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: root.highlight_color
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    padding: 20, 0
    Label:
        text: root.song
    Label:
        text: root.album
    Label:
        text: root.artist
    Button:
        size_hint_x: None
        width: 80
        text: 'Delete'
        on_release: root.delete_song()

TestBox:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    TextInput:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 48
        hint_text: 'Enter Song Name'
        multiline: False
        on_text: root.highlight_song(self.text)
    Label:
        text: 'Song List'
        size_hint_y: .1
    TouchRecycleView:
        id: rv
        viewclass: 'DraggableRow'
        data: root.rv_data_list
        scroll_type: ['bars']
        scroll_distance: 0
        bar_inactive_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
        bar_width: dp(20)
        do_scroll_x: False
        RecycleBoxLayout:
            id: rbl
            key_selection: 'song'
            default_size: None, dp(56)
            default_size_hint: 1, None
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height
            orientation: 'vertical'
"""

class DraggableRow(DragBehavior, BoxLayout):
    song = StringProperty()
    album = StringProperty()
    artist = StringProperty()
    highlight_color = ListProperty()
    index = NumericProperty()
    drag_touch = None

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(DraggableRow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.test_box = None
        self.original_index = 0
        self.drag_touch = None

    def on_parent(self, instance, value):
        if value is not None:
            self.test_box = instance

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos) and not self.drag_touch:
            self.drag_touch = touch
            self.original_index = self.parent.children.index(self)
            return super(DraggableRow, self).on_touch_down(touch)
        return super(DraggableRow, self).on_touch_down(touch)

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        if touch == self.drag_touch:
            self.y = touch.y - self.height / 2

            # Find the TestBox parent
            test_box = self.parent
            while not isinstance(test_box, TestBox):
                test_box = test_box.parent

            # Update the position in the list while still dragging
            target_index = round(self.y / self.height)
            target_index = max(0, min(target_index, len(test_box.rv_data_list) - 1))

            if self.original_index < target_index:
                target_index -= 1

            #print(f"original_index: {self.original_index}, target_index: {target_index}, y: {self.y}")

            if target_index != self.original_index:
                test_box.move_element(self.original_index, target_index)
                self.original_index = target_index

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        if touch == self.drag_touch:
            test_box = self.parent
            while not isinstance(test_box, TestBox):
                test_box = test_box.parent

            test_box.move_element(self.original_index, self.index)
            self.drag_touch = None
            return True

        return super(DraggableRow, self).on_touch_up(touch)

    def delete_song(self):
        app = App.get_running_app()
        rv = app.root.ids.rv
        del rv.data[self.index]
        for i, _ in enumerate(rv.data):
            rv.data[i]['index'] = i
        rv.refresh_from_data()

class TestBox(BoxLayout):

    elements = [{'song': f'song_{n}',
                 'album': f'album_{n}',
                 'artist': f'artist_{n}',
                 'index': n,
                 'highlight_color': [0, 0, 0, 1]} for n in range(7)]
    rv_data_list = ListProperty(elements)

    def highlight_song(self, song):
        for track in self.rv_data_list:
            track['highlight_color'] = (.8, .8, .8, 1) if song == track['song'] else (0, 0, 0, 1)
        self.ids.rv.refresh_from_data()

    def move_element(self, original_index, target_index):
        # Move the element in rv_data_list from original_index to target_index

        element = self.rv_data_list.pop(original_index)
        self.rv_data_list.insert(target_index, element)

        #print(f"data: {self.rv_data_list}")


        # Update 'index' values
        for i, element in enumerate(self.rv_data_list):
            element['index'] = i

        # Refresh the RecycleView
        self.ids.rv.refresh_from_data()

class TouchRecycleView(RecycleView):
    pass

class RVTestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)

RVTestApp().run()
```

Comment: I think using `RecycleView` may be overkill. Unless you are expecting a large number of rows (20 is not nearly large), you can use a `ScrollView` instead. Rearranging rows in a `RecycleView` is more complicated.

Comment: @John Anderson it can easy stack up to over 40

Comment: Still not nearly enough to justify using a RecycleView.